# Flask: Get modification date of uploaded file

Tags: python, flask, stat

I have a flask web application and would like to get the modification date of the uploaded files.

I am using

```
f = request.files['file']
...
f.save(secure_path_to_uploaded_file)
```

Unfortunately, if I run

```
t = os.path.getmtime(secure_path_to_uploaded_file)
time_stamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
print(time_stamp)
```

on the uploaded and saved file, I get the current date as modification date. If I run `getmtime()` on the client, I get a much older date.

How can I get the modification date of the file *before* it was uploaded? (The server runs on Linux)

Comment: Why was this closed ? The referral link is for JS not flask.

Comment: Can anyone suggest any solutions around this?